# Objects in div connected dynamically using div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

The first input creates a loop called Enter # of Circles that creates multiple divs. Each div contains a circle and an input object.

The input **Color** is supposed to change the color of the circle within the same div using an ID pulled out of divID.

The ID is pulled out of the loop yet it doesn't seem to be working most likely because of the event listener but nothing seems to work.

Any clue of what is being done wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Bins Status</title>
   <style>
      div {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 1px;
      }
   </style>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <br>
   <b>Enter # of Circles<b>
   <br>
   <input type="integer" id="circles">   
   </b></b>
   <form>
      <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
         <svg height="100" width="200">
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />
            <svg height="100" width="100">
               <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
            </svg>
         </svg>
         <br>
         <b>Color<b>
         <br>
         <input type="integer" id="Color">
         </b></b>

         <script>
            //Inputing integer 1, 2 or 3 which instantly applies color formatting (RGB) to circle in the same div
            var cir = document.getElementById("cir");
            var into = document.getElementById("Color");
            into.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, false);

            function myFunction() {
                if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 1)
                    cir.style.fill = "green";
                else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 2)
                    cir.style.fill = "red";
                else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 3)
                    cir.style.fill = "blue";
                else cir.style.fill = "Yellow";
            }
         </script>
      </div>
   </form>


   <script type="text/javascript">
      //Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input

      var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
          form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],
          ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"),
          i, timer;

      function createCircles(val) {
          // Removing previous circles
          while (form.firstChild) {
              form.removeChild(form.firstChild);
          }
          for(i = 0; i < val; i++) {
              var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
              clone.id = "Participentfieldwrap_" + i;
              clone.querySelector("input").id = "Color_" + i;
              clone.querySelector("circle").id = "cir_" + i;
              form.appendChild(clone);
          }
      }
      ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          if(timer) {
              clearTimeout(timer);
          }
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
              createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
          }, 800);
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/o96y7bf2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function calls the id "cir" and "color" and when you create circles the id is "cir_0" and "color_0". Another problem is that the new elements in the DOM do not activate the functions that were launched when the page loads.

I do not know how to do this with pure javascript but [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ecruz/4kjydgw7/23/) I leave a solution with jquery.

Greetings from Mexico.